# SQL makes key lookup instead of seek over indexed column

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have 1 large and 2 small tables inner joined. I added appropriate indexes over large table. Even if query is fast (most of the time) some times it is getting over 3 seconds. When I checked execution plan, seems like SQL goes with **key lookup** instead of **index seek**.

Here is my query;

[image]

and my execution plan;

[image]

and here execution details;

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am doubt that you have parameter sniffing `@newscategoryid`

Comment: can you confirm if you used ( `option (optimize for unknown)` ), how the query execution time will get affected ?

Comment: Please consider moving the solution from the question to an answer (you can make one). Let me know so I can upvote it.

Comment: @2501 if I create my own answer then Martin Smith's response will not be marked as answer which I do not want. You suggest me to create an answer but do not mark it?

Comment: @Teomanshipahi Yes. Just like it is now. Except your answer will be correctly in the answer section.

Comment: @2501 OK. Done. Thanks for redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key lookup is a seek. It is looking up using the key.

The non clustered index always includes the clustered index key (or physical rid if the table isn't clustered in which case you get a "bookmark lookup" instead)

Because the index used in the previous index seek does not contain the `CreateDate` column it needs to use the clustered index key to seek into the clustered index to retrieve it. This type of seek to retrieve additional columns is called a key lookup.

If you wanted to get rid of the lookup you could consider adding CreateDate as an `include`d column to the index on NewsCategoryUrlId.

Though as Hadi says in the comments your case sounds like parameter sniffing or outdated statistics. Often a plan with a non covering index seek and key lookups may be generated if the optimiser believes the parameter value to be selective and be problematic if it is not selective.

With parameter sniffing the problem can arise if a plan is compiled for a selective value and then cached and reused for a less selective value.

Outdated statistics may not reflect the true selectivity of the parameter value the plan is compiled for in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Suggestion with creating index including CreateDate and NewsCategoryUrlId seems helped. And I am getting much accurate timing.  updated my question to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

After suggestion from Martin Smith, I re-create my index as below;

[image]

and now, execution plan is mush satisfied for me;

[image]